# Gradle: Call root-task with recursive execution from subprojects

Tags: eclipse, gradle, multi-project

If i have a gradle multi-project like this

```
RootProject
+-- SubProjectA
+-- SubProjectB
```

and every project has a task 'foo', i can call it on the root project

```
RootProject>gradle foo
```

and it also gets executed for the subprojects

```
:foo
:SubProjectA:foo
:SubProjectB:foo
```

But if i call task ':foo' from a Subproject

```
RootProject\SubProjectA>gradle :foo
```

only the task on root project gets executed

```
:foo
```

but not the 'foo' tasks on the subprojects.

Is there a way to call 'foo' on all projects while being in a subproject? I'm asking this because i am using the gradle eclipse plug-in and there i only have access to the subprojects, i.e. the projects that i see in eclipse.

By the way: The (somewhat hacky) solution i came up with so far

```
task fooAll(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '..'
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'gradle foo'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving of task *names* (e.g. `foo`) to tasks is a function of the *start directory*, which defaults to the current directory. You can change the start directory with the `-p` command line option (see `gradle --help`). So you'd have to do something like `gradle foo -p ../`.

Also importing the root project might be a better way to solve your Eclipse problem. The Eclipse tooling handles hierarchical directory layouts very well.

PS: `:foo` is a task *path*. It refers to the task named `foo` in the root project (`:`).

Comment: I importet the root project into eclipse (didn't know that this is possible, but it is), made it a gradle project and now i can call tasks on the root project. Unfortunately the gradle eclipse plugin calls the tasks in a qualified way, i.e. it calls ':foo' instead of 'foo'. So only task 'foo' on the root projects gets executed.

Comment: I was wondering if the plugin supports task names already, but your question sounded as if it did. Do you have the latest version?

Comment: My plug-in version is 3.1.0.201210040512. And according to eclipse update and the marketplace client there is no update. So far i haven't found a way to change the Gradle Launch Configurations to use task names instead of paths.

Comment: From what I can tell, it isn't supported yet, and you have to select the tasks individually.